Auto Adjust HTML Embed Box
My Google website includes html embed blocks in between textboxes. Opening the website with a small window/small screen, those embed blocks collapse to small scrollable windows themselves. Here's an example:



The first text is added via a html embed box while the identical text is added below using a textbox from Google. As I open the draft website on a small screen, the html text collapses into a small "window" with its own scroll bar (see the red number 1) whereas the text in the Google textbox simply breaks up and extends the entire site's scroll bar (see the red number 2).
Question: Can I change the html code such that it does not create a smaller window but simply adjusts its size corresponding to the screen size (ie, behaves like a Google textbox)?
Note: I use html embed blocks to add features beyond simple text (eg I add images and want the text to wrap around the image). I only show the plain text here to illustrate the problem.
Here's the HTML code for the little paragraph
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>

</style></head> <body>

<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>

</body></html>


"Can I change the html code" Maybe. You didn't post any code so there's not much we can say. See [mcve]

@j08691 Fair point, thanks a lot! Is it any clearer now? Do you happen to have any suggestions?

If the Google Website system doesn't offer any option for that, then I suppose you could only try and implement it yourself - you'll need something similar to an "iframe resizer" script then, something that measures the height of the content of that embed, and then explicitly sets that height for the HTML element that is actually used to implement the "embedding" on the parent page. (Since the content you supply is a full HTML document, I suppose that must be either an iframe, object or embed element.)

@CBroe Thanks a lot for your comment. Google indeed doesn't offer any solution for that. I can kind of follow intuitively what you suggest but I frankly am very new to html - could you help me with implementing your proposed solution?

Figure out what element it actually uses for those embeds (inspect the page using your browser dev tools) first of all. I suspect it will just be an iframe, but I don't know. Iframe resizer scripts are not a new thing, they have been around for a long time - do a bit of research. (I am guessing that the embed content gets loaded from the same origin as the "main" page here, so you should not need anything complex that handles cross-origin communication via postMessage.)
